# upload image on server

Tags: php, html, image, upload

hi friends i am following this link http://code.google.com/p/upload-at-click/ to upload image i have one HTML, one server side php file for moving uploaded pic and some dependent .js files 
iam facing 2 problem :
1. my code runs fine but i do not find image in my given path /folder when i have my server in same machine.
2. i cannot make connection with server when it on different machine i.e --> using ip address

here is my code
Server side scripting .php file

```
<?php
$tmp_file_name = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$ok = move_uploaded_file($tmp_file_name, '/image/');

// This message will be passed to 'oncomplete' function
echo $ok ? "OK" : "FAIL";
 ?>
```

my html file

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>upload-at-click demo</title> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="upclick-min.js"></script>
<!--http://code.google.com/p/upload-at-click/-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="upclick.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<h1>Demo</h1>
<ol>
  <li>Click on the button</li>
  <li>Select file in "Open file" dialog</li>
  <li>Click Open</li>
</ol>
And you will see message: 'Starting upload: &ltfile name&gt'<br>
Then, after file uploaded, you will see message: 'Uploaded!'.
<br>
<br>

<input type="button" id="uploader" value="Upload">

 <script type="text/javascript">

   var uploader = document.getElementById('uploader');

   upclick(
     {
      element: uploader,
      action: 'test.php', // path to server php file for storing image . 
      onstart:
        function(filename)
        {
         // alert('Start upload: ' + filename);
        },
      oncomplete:
        function(response_data) 
        {
          alert(response_data);
        }
     });

   </script>


</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `move_uploaded_file` function should have as the second parameter the full path of the image so you have to replace `/your_path/` with `/your_path/your_file_name.extension`. That should solve your problem

Comment: ok and now how cani make connection when my php file is on other machine do u know ?

Comment: If your interested about using FTP uploads with PHP please read documentation of `ftp_put` at http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that

```
$path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/images/";

$tmp_file_name = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$ok = move_uploaded_file($tmp_file_name, $path);
```